# How to make method that deletes arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, constructor

I am learning how to make constructors in Javascript, so far so good but I am struggling how to make an method that will delete specific items from the array.

I want whenever I call Manager.fireEmployee(nameOfEmployee) to delete that employee from the array.

Also is there a way whenever I create new employee from the constructor that will be pushed automatically inside the array?

Here is the code:

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name, department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }
    whoAreYou() {
        return `My name is ${this.name} and I am working in ${this.department} department`;
    }
};

class Manager extends Employee {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, 'General');
    }
    fireEmployee(nameOfEmployee){
        // how to make this method so when I type the name of the employee it will remove it from the array?
    }
};

class SalesPerson extends Employee {
    constructor(name, quota) {
        super(name, 'Sales', quota);
        this.quota = quota;
    }
};

let michael = new Manager('Michael');
let pam = new Employee('Pam', 'Marketing');
let jim = new SalesPerson('Jim', '1000');
let dwight = new SalesPerson('Dwight', '1200');

let arr = [pam, jim, dwight];
```

Comment: Use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete item from the Array and [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the item to array.
I hope you will find [Array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) useful.

Comment: Probably this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/2782135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a slightly different approach for you `Manager` class, making it hold the employees as an array. Then you can call all the methods to manipulate the employees array easily from your `Manager` instance, e.g.

```
michael.addEmployee(pam);
michael.fireEmployee(pam);
```

---

```
class Manager extends Employee {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, 'General');
        this.employees = [];
    }

    addEmployee(employee) {
        if (employee) this.employees.push(employee);
    }

    fireEmployee(employee){
        this.employees.splice(this.employees.indexOf(employee), 1);
    }

    getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }
}
```

Now try this:

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(name, department) {
    this.name = name;
    this.department = department;
  }
  whoAreYou() {
    return `My name is ${this.name} and I am working in ${this.department} department`;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name, 'General');
    this.employees = [];
  }

  addEmployee(employee) {
    if (employee) this.employees.push(employee);
  }

  fireEmployee(employee) {
    this.employees.splice(this.employees.indexOf(employee), 1);
  }

  getEmployees() {
    return this.employees;
  }
}

class SalesPerson extends Employee {
  constructor(name, quota) {
    super(name, 'Sales', quota);
    this.quota = quota;
  }
}



let michael = new Manager('Michael');
let pam = new Employee('Pam', 'Marketing');
let jim = new SalesPerson('Jim', '1000');
let dwight = new SalesPerson('Dwight', '1200');

michael.addEmployee(pam);
michael.addEmployee(jim);
michael.addEmployee(dwight);

console.log(michael.getEmployees());

michael.fireEmployee(pam);

console.log(michael.getEmployees());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to delete the class instance as well as from array here is the solution.

```
fireEmployee(nameOfEmployee){
    var arrayIdx;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i].name == nameOfEmployee){
       arrayIdx = i;
      }
    }
    delete arr.splice(arrayIdx,1); // removes from the array as well as the class instance
    }
```

and to push you can use the push method `arr.push(employeeClassInstance)` in your function